# Laravel 8: photo_id does not added to users table at One To Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 to develop my project and in this project, I have a page for adding new users and uploading their profile picture.

Now at the `store()` of Controller, I coded this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
        'name' => 'required|min:4',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'status' => 'required',
        'role' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ])->validated();

    if($file = $request->file('avatar')){
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $photo = new Photo();
        $photo->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $photo->path = $name;
        $photo->user_id = Auth::id();
        $photo->save();

        $user->photo_id = $photo->id;   //Adding photo id to the new user at users table
     }

      $creation = User::create([
          'name' => $validate_data['name'],
           'email' => $validate_data['email'],
           'status' => $validate_data['status'],
           'role_id' => $validate_data['role'],
           'password' => bcrypt($validate_data['password'])
       ]);

       if($creation){
           alert()->success('User was added', 'Success');
           return redirect('/admin/users/');
        } else {
            return '1003';
        }
    }
```

It works fine and correct and adds the new user to `users` table and the photo to `photos` table.

But this line that should add the `photo_id` to `users` table, does not work and the `photo_id` of the new user is empty somehow!

And the relationship between User and Photo Models goes like this:

`User.php`:

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
}
```

`Photo.php`:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And I have also added `photo_id` as `fillbale` at User Model.

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion about this...

Thanks in advance.

Here are the Migrations, if you would like to see:

`create_photos_table` table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('path');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

`add_avatar_to_users_table`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('photo_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `add_avatar_to_users_table` migration change `integer` to `bigInteger` as follows:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('photo_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    });
}
```

Remove the following line from code:

```
$user = new User();
```

Update the following chunk of code:

```
$creation = User::create([
    'name' => $validate_data['name'],
    'email' => $validate_data['email'],
    'status' => $validate_data['status'],
    'role_id' => $validate_data['role'],
    'password' => bcrypt($validate_data['password']),
    'photo_id' => isset($photo) ? $photo->id : null
]);
```

Comment: but why should he define a photo_id if he has a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think tejoslaeslio want to store one image against each user. If it is so he has to change the relation as follows: 

public function photo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Photo::class);
}

Comment: exactly, that is confusing me :)

Comment: @tejoslaeslio what do you want here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save that model:

```
$user->save()
```

Otherwise the the change you made has no effect to the DB

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things:

1. If your users can have many photos then you won't need the photo_id on your users table, because all photos have a user_id, hence the one to many relationship
2. You define  `$user = new User()` and assign the value to this object. But later you are creating an new User with this code:

```
 $creation = User::create([
            'name' => $validate_data['name'],
            'email' => $validate_data['email'],
            'status' => $validate_data['status'],
            'role_id' => $validate_data['role'],
            'password' => bcrypt($validate_data['password'])
        ]);
```

Therefore you have 2 User models and only one of them gets saved to the database.

And last, if you save the auth()->id() as the user_id of your photo the photo will not belong to the correct user. You will first have to create the user and then take this id.

Answer (score 0):

some code of your store is wrong
at first you use

```
 $user = new User();
```

after

```
$creation = User::create([
    'name' => $validate_data['name'],
    'email' => $validate_data['email'],
    'status' => $validate_data['status'],
    'role_id' => $validate_data['role'],
    'password' => bcrypt($validate_data['password'])
]);
```

use this code

```
$user->name=$validate_data['name'];
$user->email=$validate_data['email'];
$user->status=$validate_data['status'];
$user->role_id=$validate_data['role'];
$user->password=bcrypt($validate_data['password']);
$user->save();
```